# ASCII translator on input

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand about cesar cipher, how it's works, trying to solve this for my homework, but nothing come in my mind. I tried this code, but there's no return on input.
i already maded everything, but the only things that miss in this work is making char code work on a input

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button")
const input = document.getElementById("input").value;
button.onclick = function() {
  var texto = input2.charCodeAt().value
  input.innerHTML = texto;
}
```

```html
<h1>ASCII</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Coding</button>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Say it</span>
  <input id="id1" type="text" class="form-control" name="text1" maxLength="1">

</div>
<p id="demo" style="color:red;"></p>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any element with the ID `input` anywhere, so what are you expecting `document.getElementById("input")` to select?

Comment: ...same goes for `document.getElementById("button")`

Comment: And you’re getting the value of the non-existent “input” id element. Seems like you’d want to grab the input string, iterate over it, and transform each character based on your cipher.

Comment: Here‘s a guide on how to use `document.getElementById()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById?retiredLocale=de

Answer (score 0):

I did it, there was a problem not only with DOM, but also with textarea, idk how to make a input as a output for put the char code.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Working ASCII</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>ASCII</h1>
  
  <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Coding</button>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <input id="input" type="text" class="form-control" name="text1" maxLength="1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <br>
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">ASCII CODE</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    <script>
const button = document.getElementById("button")
button.onclick = function() {
    alert("ASCII")
    var str = document.getElementById("input");
    if (str.value=="") {
       str.focus();
       return;
       
    }
document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1").innerText = str.value.charCodeAt(0);
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```